# Returning Null Values in a Stored Procedure with Pivot

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, pivot, ssrs-2012

I need to return 0 instead of null values in my stored procedure. Isnull will not work in the Pivot portion. I am trying to sum up these values in an SSRS report, but since there are nulls I am just getting blanks.

```html
USE [LTWS1]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[QB_BALANCE_SHEET]    Script Date: 6/29/2015 6:55:04 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[QB_BALANCE_SHEET]

@pDate datetime


as
SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @AccountRef_Fullname AS  NVARCHAR(MAX)



select  @AccountRef_Fullname = COALESCE(@AccountRef_Fullname + ',', '') + '['+ AccountRef_Fullname + ']'

from 
(
select distinct fullname as AccountRef_Fullname 
from account)pAccountRef_Full_Name


declare  @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)


set @Sql = N' SELECT [DATE],  ' + @AccountRef_Fullname

+ 'from 

(SELECT  *    from Balance_Summary_View
where [DATE] <= ''' + CAST(@pDate AS varchar(31)) + '''

   )Account_Data '
                          
+' PIVOT ('
+ '  sum(amount)   for   AccountRef_FullName in ('+ @AccountRef_Fullname +')'
+'  )  AS PivotTable '


--+' )Data '
 exec (@Sql)

 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way you can fix that SQL, because You need to apply the isnull in the select, which is difficult since you have a dynamic select list. I toyed with the idea of suggesting using a replace on the string to put the isnulls in, but you couldn't get the columns aliased correctly with a simple replace.

Then it hit me, why not just use an expression in SSRS to change the display. Something along the lines of

```
=Iif(isnothing(amount.value), 0, amount.value)
```

Now for the unsolicited advice, You could also use a tablix in SSRS to make that whole pivot using dynamic sql unnecessary. Hope that helps :)

Comment: BRILLIANT!!!! Thank you, I was completely over thinking it. This solved my issue nicely.